# Mongo/Node.js VSCode Dev container - how to see mongo container in terminal?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-code, terminal, containers

I'm using the VSCode Dev Container for Mongo/Node.js - When the terminal comes up for the "container" it is the Node.js container. What is the easy way to get the Mongo container up in a terminal? I eventually got it by attaching to a running terminal in a new vscode windows then using that terminal but maybe there is a better way.

I would think "Open in terminal" would be an option

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code's Remote-Containers is currently limited to a single container per window. There is a feature request to allow for multiple containers: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1460